How can I change the background brush for a window class?
I need to change the background brush for a window, when a user enters dragging an OLE object.
My code is as follows.
SetClassLongA is actually called. hWnd, DragBrush are OK.
But the background of the window hWnd does not changed. What am I doing wrong?
Is it right to use SetClassLongA in order to change the window background?
// IDropTarget implementation
virtual HRESULT __stdcall DragEnter(IDataObject* pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD* pdwEffect) override {
 
    std::cout << "               OLE -> DragEnter." << std::endl;
 
    *pdwEffect = DROPEFFECT_COPY;
 
    HBRUSH DragBrush = CreateHatchBrush(HS_CROSS, RGB(255, 0, 0));
 
    if (DragBrush == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error creating dragging brush_2" << std::endl;
    }

    DWORD OldBrush = SetClassLongA(hWnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG) DragBrush);

    BOOL ok1 = InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    BOOL ok2 = UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    // ok1=ok2=1   OK
 
 
    return S_OK;
}


Just because a window has a default brush assigned doesn't guarantee it is actually used. It depends on the window's actual painting code. Do you own the hWnd? Are you handling its WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT messages?

Remy Lebeau, thank you for the fast reply! I control hWnd, but the mentioned events are not handled . I am new in WinApi drawing. Do you mean - I have to draw empty rectangle by myself ?

@LUN Are you targeted on 32 bit window? Have you tried using SetWindowLongPtr?

@Torrecto, I have compiled my program with Debug x64 config. Why are you telling about SetWindow... - I need to change the background brush. But SetClassLongA... does it. Or no ?

@LUN Sorry I meaned setClassLongPtrA. My bad.

You can see remarks, it says: Use the SetClassLong function with care. For example, it is possible to change the background color for a class by using SetClassLong, but this change does not immediately repaint all windows belonging to the class.
So you need to use GetClientRect and FillRect to redraw the client area.
I used Visual Studio's project sample. See, here is your purple window before redraw:

When we add GetClientRect and FillRect. It shows correct color as I made the read one:

The code in WM_PAINT message:
case WM_PAINT:
    {

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(220, 0, 0));
        ULONG_PTR res = SetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)hBrush);
        //DeleteObject(hBrush);

        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        int res1= FillRect(hdc, &rect, hBrush);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }


The OP isn't relying on immediate, automatic repaint. The code explicitly calls InvalidateRect and UpdateWindow, making sure to pass the flag to request background erasure.

OK, thanks to all for your replies! You have helped me!
